# MySQL Count DATETIME Entries by Hour

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with a DATETIME column in it. I want to count the number of entries that have the DATETIME field set to each hour of the day.

For example a row with the value 2012-12-18 22:05:20 would clock-in at 22:00:00 (10pm). An entry with 2013-09-25 12:29:58 would clock-in at 12:00:00 (12pm). I do not need to know the date, just which hour the entries occur on.

My DATETIME field is called date_time. Any ideas on how to count entries by hour? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function [`HOUR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) that returns exactly that.

So you could do something like

```
select hour(date_time), count(*) from tableName group by hour(date_time)
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4257/3)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT DATEADD(HH,DATEDIFF(HH,0,date_time),0) AS dt_hour, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM tbl
GROUP BY DATEADD(HH,DATEDIFF(HH,0,date_time),0)
```

Effectively it finds the number of hours between the zero date and your date_time field and then adds that number of hours to the zero date. This strips off any minutes and seconds but leaves the date and hour. This allows you to aggregate by hour for every day...

UPDATE:
When I read your question I missed the bit about the actual date not being important. MySQL has a function called HOUR() that will return the hour from a DATETIME value. So you can do this:

```
SELECT HOUR(date_time) AS dt_hour, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM tbl
GROUP BY HOUR(date_time)
```